# What does the "design" tag even mean? Do we want it?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently eight questions tagged "design".

- [Asteroid as a generation ship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/377/29)
- [Foundation Component of New World](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/332/29)
- [Ensuring consistency in a world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/325/29)
- [Can you simply scale up animals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/316/29)
- [Ship design that could navigate on the edge of an incredibly strong vortex](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/68/29)
- [For designing a vocal language for an intelligent species, how to decide on phonemes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/58/29)
- [Are geographically typed planets realistic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/40/29)
- [How can I break down the task of creating a world into manageable chunks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2/29)

At a glance, these don't really have a lot in common.

Only one ("Foundation Component of New World") is tagged *only* [design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) whereas the others have additional tags as well.

What exactly do we intend the [design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag to *mean* in this case? Can we even deduce a meaning for the tag from the mass of questions tagged with it, or should we simply drop that tag entirely?

**Since worldbuilding almost by definition relates to some sort of design, I think we can drop the tag entirely.** How does the community feel?

Comment: Uh oh, I'm the guilty party at least twice there! I think you're right - everything we do here is design. Context is more valuable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually despite the fact I've said a few times now that I think it's too early for a tag cull...in this case I agree, the tag is pretty meaningless.

Comment: I would probably feel differently if the tag had a clear meaning; then I might be more willing to say "let's wait and see what happens". But in this case, I can't see any community consensus *at all* in its use.

Comment: I agree - it serves no purpose. Following the tag won't bring you tailored questions that suit you. Browsing the tag won't give you any better insight than picking questions at random. Applying the tag doesn't tell answerers anything about what is being looked for.

Comment: Totally agree, in fact, I went an edited the one question with only the "Design" tag, and changed it to an "foundation" tag. I think that describes the question better. (Foundation will be things that are done before the world is fully formed, laying the foundation).

Comment: The term does have quite a few interpretations. In my own questions (on ship design) I used it to indicate that I was looking for something akin to a physical "template", but this is only one of a myriad of interpretations, as @MichaelKjörling has shown us. I guess in worldbuilding "design" really is a meaningless tag.

Comment: @ChristianFratta Yes. ship-design (or to be more specific maybe water-vessel-design to distinguish it from spaceship-design although that's rather a mouthful) would be a useful tag, design by itself not so much.

Comment: Even I agree with culling this one early on. If @ChristianFratta, you want a tag for a template, what about blueprint?

Comment: @Mourdos I think template actually works well enough for that purpose, blueprint seems a little too narrow a tag to me