# Should we keep the "sci-fi" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I notice that many of my questions on Worldbuilding meta are along these lines, but hey, everyone else seems to have already asked the good questions.

Okay. To the point at hand. I've seen the [sci-fi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sci-fi) tag used recently, and I'm wondering what it adds to questions. It doesn't have a tag summary (which is part of what makes me reach for the ax), and the questions it uses (mostly) don't seem to be solidly based in sci-fi - at least, not to the extent that science fiction is the primary concern of the question.

Possible arguments against this:

[Please revisit this timely on-hold question soon](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/please-revisit-this-timely-on-hold-question-soon)

["Resource ID" questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/resource-id-questions)

That is, if these ideas go through the gauntlet of meta - which they very well may; I can't say yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [sci-fi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sci-fi) tag is currently used on three questions:

- [What would hinder the exploration of an alien outpost?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11853/29), tagged technology alien exploration sci-fi (I'm sure this can be retagged better, but sci-fi seems to not add anything substantial in terms of classification of the question)
- [Could air gas giants exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11764/29), tagged science-based planets sci-fi (seems covered by the science-based planets tag pair, so sci-fi does not really add anything substantial)
- [hypothetical criteria for non-paradox FTL](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10461/29), tagged science-based physics faster-than-light sci-fi (the first three seem to fit quite well, but again sci-fi doesn't add anything substantial)

In **none of these do I see the sci-fi tag adding** any substantial classification of the respective question. The whole field of science-fiction is also very broad (heck, there's [a *whole site* for it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)!), and the concept also covers a great deal of what we do here (similar to [the design tag that we had for a short while](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/29)) so it is doubtful whether the tag adds any meaningful classification at all; it appears more like a meta tag, which is something we generally should be careful with.

I believe the tag can safely be removed from all three questions without any significant loss, and it is my feeling that **we do not need the sci-fi tag at all.** It can thus be removed from the questions and be allowed to die an honorable death.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. By the way, we now have a [tag:science-fiction] tag. Should that go the same way?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of [repeating myself](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/modifying-the-science-fantasy-tag/1874#1874):

### Genre names do not qualify how the question should be answered!

Questioners can limit answers to be either [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based), [fantasy-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-based) or accept both.

You might want to give your question some context to get answers that feel natural to the world your building. However, telling your genre is not going to help. Have a look at the following question.

> I am writing a novel about semi-intelligent **zombies** working as mascots in a **horror theme park** encountering weird situations with visitors. How could a zombie try to prove he is just a human in a costume in case he is forced to?
>
> [horror](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)[comedy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)

Do you really think this hypothetical question will get better answers because of its – also fictitious – genre tags?